# Get properties of outlook emails

Tags: c#, outlook

My c sharp program currently gets outlook emails and imports them into a dataset. However, I am only getting the subject of each email.

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder olCurrFolder;` which I use this variable to get the subject (olCurrFolder gets set from another loop). In order to get the subject I do this:

```
intMailCount = olCurrFolder.Items.Count;

for (int i = 1; i <= intMailCount; i++)
{
    strSubject = olCurrFolder.Items[i].Subject;
    strEmailReceived = olCurrFolder.Items[i].Received;
}
```

As you can see, I am also trying to get the received date, but `Items[i].Received` does not work. The intellisense does not pull up anything when I type a period after `Items[i]` and a message says it will be resolved at runtime. I have no idea what the other fields are called (i.e. Received Date, From, Size).

Is there a list that has the field names I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the Outlook MailItem object is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210946(v=office.11).aspx

You can use the `ReceivedTime` property to get the received date and time.

The reason that intellisense sometimes doesn't work with VSTO is that many of the properties return a `dynamic`. A dynamic is treated like an object that supports every method and property imaginable. This is what prevents intellisense from working. If you use a nonexistent method, it will compile, but fail at runtime.

I find the MSDN documentation is invaluable when working with dynamics in VSTO.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find it on google. FYI, under properties on that page, it has a property called ReceivedTime. This property gives me the Received Date and Time together, so that worked perfect. To anyone else trying to do the same thing, you have to put ToString() after like this: Items[i].ReceivedTime.ToString()

Comment: Oh, yes. I saw a list of properties and didn't see the time on it, so I assumed it wasn't there. I should have looked through the Properties section. :)

Comment: No biggie, those properties are kind of jumbled on that page, so it is easy to overlook something. And, one would assume that "Time" means Time not Date and Time.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it

```
for (int i = 1; i <= items.Count; i++)
{
    if (items[i] is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        SenderName = ((Outlook.MailItem)inbox.Items[i]).SenderName;
        SenderEmail =((Outlook.MailItem)inbox.Items[i]).SenderEmailAddress;
        Subject = ((Outlook.MailItem)inbox.Items[i]).Subject;
        Time = ((Outlook.MailItem)inbox.Items[i]).CreationTime.ToString();
```

Comment: Do not use multiple dot notation. Besides being extremely inefficient, you will run out of RPC channels in the online Exchange mode. Retrieve the item only once as the beginning of the loop and release it using Marshal.ReleaseComObject when you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to cast the object for each line you can do this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            var mailItem = items[i] as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (mailItem != null)
            {
                SenderName = mailItem.SenderName;
                //etc...
            }
        }
```